# Change password of PDF file

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can i change the password of a pdf file programmatically?

I have multiple pdf files in a folder and I want to change the password of all of them. I load the pdfs as described in the [Quartz 2D Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF109)

I can check if it is password protected, unlock it with the password, display it, but i can't change the password. Any help is appreciated.